# Parametrizing Tornado RequestHandler

Tags: python, web-services, tornado

Let's say I have a very simple web app in python Tornado framework with a single endpoint. All I'm interested in is returning a value calculated before starting the server. Slightly modified example from https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html will do just fine.

**handler.py**

```
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('I want to return var `expensive_value`')
```

**main.py**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # calculate some var here before starting the server
    expensive_value = 'value from long_calculation()'
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

When running `python main.py` and sending a request to the endpoint it returns only a string of course. But I'd like to return the actual value of `expensive_value`. Currently I'm aware of two solutions to the problem.

### 1. Using global variable in handler

**handler.py**

```
import tornado.web


global_variable = None


def setter(val):
    global global_variable
    global_variable = val


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(global_variable)
```

**main.py**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

from handler import MainHandler, setter


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expensive_value = 'value from long_calculation()'
    setter(expensive_value)
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Having a global var and setting its value from some other module sounds like an antipattern to me.

### 2. Using initialize method in handler

**handler.py**

```
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, expensive_value):
        self.expensive_value = expensive_value

    def get(self):
        self.write(self.expensive_value)
```

**main.py**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

from handler import MainHandler


def make_app(parameter):
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler, {'expensive_value': parameter}),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expensive_value = 'value from long_calculation()'
    app = make_app(expensive_value)
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

This solution is better. But `initialize` method is called for every request. I realize the overhead for that would be rather small but I think it might be misleading for potential reader of the code since `expensive_value` never changes.

### Summary

Both of these solution work. But I don't like any of them and it seems like I'm missing some Tornado functionality. **What would be a pythonic way to solve this?**

For example I believe Flask has `app.config` dictionary that is accessible in handlers and it seems to be a nice solution to this as `expensive_value` is indeed a configuration to the app. But I'm not aware of anything similar in Tornado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handlers have access to `self.application.settings` which is a dictionary containing additional arguments passed to the `Application` constructor.

So you can pass `expensive_value` directly to the `Application` class like this:

```
def make_app(parameter):
    return tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ],

        expensive_value=parameter
    )
```

And access this value in any handler like this:

```
def initialize(self):
    self.expensive_value = self.application.settings.get('expensive_value')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.